# nginx auth_basic errors: user not found and no user/password provided

Tags: nginx

I have set auth basic in nginx and blocked other ips like:

```
location / {
   auth_basic "Restricted Area";
   auth_basic_user_file .htpasswd;
   allow 127.0.0.1;
   deny all;
}
```

I can login using the `username/password` provided in `.htpasswd` but the error log in nginx shows errors like:

```
user "memcache" was not found in "/etc/nginx/.htpasswd"
no user/password was provided for basic authentication
```

Any suggestion why this occurs and how to get rid of it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not be the perfect solutions, but I had to add `memcache` as the new user to `.htpasswd` file. Now, I don't have that error of `user not found`. But that `no user/password was provided for basic authentication` is still occurring. I had explored all over and found this post from `Igor Sysoev` The creator of Nginx:

> The HTTP Basic authentication works as following:
>
> - A browser requests a page without user/password.
> - A server response with 401 page, sending realm as well.
> - At this stage the 401 code appears in access_log and the message       "no user/password ..." appears in error_log.
> - The browser shows a realm/login/password prompt.
> - If a user will press cancel, then the browser will show the received 401 page.
> - If the user enters login/password, then the browser repeats the request with login/password.
>
> Then until you will exit the browser, it will send these
>   login/password with all requests in protected hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

I did not have to add the user memcache rather I only had to install memcached and then it worked for me.

```
server {
        # Change these settings to match your machine
        listen 80;
        server_name yourdomain.com;

           satisfy any;

           allow 127.0.0.1;
           deny all;

        # Restrict Access
           auth_basic  "Restricted";
           auth_basic_user_file /var/www/.htpasswd;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/domain_access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/domain_error.log;

        # deny access to .htaccess files
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

}
```

Comment: `memcache` and `memcached` are almost similar how they work, so, adding **memcached** instead shouldn't really solve the issue, given I have installed **memcached** too. As **Igor** said `Nginx` checks for authentication with every browser request. All browsers cache the internal auth and doesn't prompt for password everytime, so **Nginx**  logs this as auth failure.